# onReceive() function of a broadcastreceiver is not called, Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I am trying to establish a basic alarm service. The code for set up the alarm looks like this. I have 15 minutes interval just to see if anything happens.

```
       val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
       val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
       val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
           applicationContext,
           0,
           intent,
           PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

       val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
       calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20)
       calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40)
       calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.timeInMillis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent)
```

I registered the receiver in the manifest file:

```
   <application>
   ...
       <receiver
           android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
           android:enabled="true"
           android:exported="false" />

   </application>
```

in addition i defined a permission, too in the manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

The onReceive function of the AlarmReceiver class is not called.
I have a println line included. It does not print out anything.

I have no idea what I can do to make the alarm working.
Any hints are welcome.

thank you in advance
br,
Peter

Comment: Replace `PendingIntent.getActivity()` with `PendingIntent.getReceiver()`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. getBroadcast() works as no getReceiver() exist. So, it works now. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was writing that from memory. I am glad that you got it working, though! Consider writing your own answer to the question!

Answer (score 0):

Use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` when creating the `PendingIntent` instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity()`